# Word 2010: Sentence right under picture

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-office-2010, pictures

What I want to get is something like, that:

[image]

the screenshot is from webpage. But I want to get this result on Word 2010, under absolutely aligned picture. Is that possible? If yes, how to get this result? thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried right clicking and selecting Insert Caption?  Is this what you want?

[image: Word 2010 Picture right click menu][image: Word 2010 Picture with caption]

Answer (score 0):

In those cases where the caption function doesn't give me enough options, I use a border-less table to place the picture and text the way I want. You can position and re-size the table as you need to work with your document.

Place the text in the cell below the image and adjust text properties as needed. For this example I left the borders on the table so you could see the cells.

[image]

Otherwise it looks like this with the borders removed.

[image]

Comment: Using the options in the Insert Caption will allow you to create a borderless table.  It will also link the two for you automatically.